# Bind dropdown to knockout value from external modal

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a view model containing 2 arrays. One array is an array of users, and the other is an array of user levels.

```
{
  "Users": [
    {
      "UserLevel": {
        "Permissions": [],
        "Id": 2,
        "Name": "Developer",
        "SortOrder": 1,
        "IsHidden": false
      },
      "Id": 1,
      "Username": "Björn Jakobsson",
      "Password": null,
      "Fullname": null,
      "Email": "bjiorn@bjinteractive.se",
      "Phone": null
    }
  ],
  "UserLevels": ko.observableArray([
  {
    "Permissions": [],
    "Id": 1,
    "Name": "Admin",
    "SortOrder": 2,
    "IsHidden": false
  },
  {
    "Permissions": [],
    "Id": 2,
    "Name": "Developer",
    "SortOrder": 1,
    "IsHidden": false
  }
])
}
```

and the drop down

```
<select data-bind="options: $parent.UserLevels(), optionsText:'Name', value: UserLevel" class="form-control"></select>
```

While editing a user from the user array i have a dropdown for choosing user level of this user wich is populated from the *UserLevels* array. If I choose a user level (in this case Developer) and saves the value in my database is saved and everything, and a reload of the page shows the correct value, but as soon as I choose to edit the user (using a bootstrap modal and with-data binding, the drop down automatically selects Admin (first in the array) and not Developer from my user model, and then the user model is updated since the user level of the user is bound to the drop down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get around the problem with my own biding instead for *value*. Below is the code I use. Any drawbacks or mistace to edit? I'm pretty new to KO and still have problems sometimes when to use unwrap, unwrapobservable etc, but below code works. Ideas for improvement?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.valueBasedOnObject = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var prop = allBindings().optionsValue;
        var value = valueAccessor();

        $(element).change(function () {
            var value = $(element).val();
            var selectedModel = ko.utils.arrayFirst(ko.unwrap(allBindings().options()), function (item) {
                return ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item[prop]) == value;
            });

            valueAccessor()(selectedModel);
        });


        var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);

        $(element).val(valueUnwrapped[prop]);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
       /* */
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your binding is incorrect. You are not binding to the observable array, but instead to what the observable array resolves to (i.e. the array)

Use

```
options: $parent.UserLevels
```

instead of

```
options: $parent.UserLevels()
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put it as a comment rather than an answer. It wasn't  directed directly at the problem you're having, more as a comment so you don't run into different issues later.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add an `optionsValue` binding.

From [**doc**](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

> Typically you’d only want to use optionsValue as a way of ensuring
>   that KO can correctly retain selection when you update the set of
>   available options. For example, if you’re repeatedly getting a list of
>   “car” objects via Ajax calls and want to ensure that the selected car
>   is preserved, you might need to set optionsValue to "carId" or
>   whatever unique identifier each “car” object has, otherwise KO won’t
>   necessarily know which of the previous “car” objects corresponds to
>   which of the new ones.

Comment: If i add optionsValue like below, my observable on my user gets value "2" instead of the actual user level object.

<select data-bind="options: $parent.UserLevels, optionsText:'Name', value: UserLevel, optionsValue: 'Id'" class="form-control"></select>